# OpenStack's Ceilometer metering notifications export to kafka - Most efficient way

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, openstack, ceilometer

as in the subject I need to put the defined metrics' measures on a kafka topic in order to feed our monitoring system.
I've seen that Ceilometer's Kafka publisher is deprecated so it's not a deal, but it's possible to:

- configure the publisher for writing to a file;
- use a notifier like amqp, even if in this case is not clear if I've
  to setup an external broker.

Both solutions seem compliant with Kafka-Connect.
Can anybody share his/her experience about this stuff?  OpenStack's documentation is a little poor about this topic (at least for me).
Any suggestion would be of help.
Thanks for your time
ny

Answer (score 0):

As you said, kafka publisher was deprecated in very new version due to adapt ceilometer-gnocchi solution. But this doesn't mean that you can not use the deprecated code and former abilities.

You can just configure kafka publisher in pipeline.yaml file directly.

```
---
sources:
    - name: meter_kafka
      interval: 600
      meters:
          - "*"
      sinks:
          - kafka_sink
sinks:
    - name: kafka_sink
      transformers:
      publishers:
          - kafka://[kafka_broker_ip]:[kafka_broker_port]?topic=[topic]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Unfortunately our OS distribution is Red Hat's one and to implement a solution based on a deprecated component leads to a broken support contract.
They haven't an out-of-the-box solution for but this need should be addressed in order to have a performance management solution.
BR

Comment: @user2523783 So what you mean is that you guys can't modify its source code? If so, you have lots of works to go.

Comment: The problem is our operation department needs support for the everyday activities (we're an engineering dept.) and a blueprint has been agreed with RedHat but it doesn't include the use of deprecated code.
We're way from devops....